# My laptop shuts down when I remove the charger

Tags: hardware

My laptop shuts down when the charger is removed.  Additionally, I get a message when booting up saying

```
disk drive for /media/3936-3939 is not ready or not present.
```

About a week ago I was trying to install a MATLAB ISO file using mount commands etc...
I tried `mount`, `fuseiso`, and `UNETbootin`.  I have a feeling this may have something to do with message I'm getting from booting up.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or help me out.

Comment: If you go to your laptop's [BIOS setup screen](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/accessbios.htm) and then remove the charger, does it still turn off? (Feel free to edit your question to include additional details as you uncover them.)

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop shutting down when it's unplugged sounds like a battery issue. I've had the battery in my laptop burn out before as well and this is the symptom. Simply order a new battery from your manufacturer and you should be all set (also, eBay has lots of aftermarket batteries on the cheap).

The message you receive at boot could be two things:

1) You might be using an encrypted swap partition. If you don't know what this is then it's probably not the case (and it usually shows up as /dev/cryptswap1). This is the issue I get upon startup and it is because the swap partition is being wiped.

2) More likely, there is an invalid entry in your /etc/fstab file. At boot Linux attempts to mount all entries in the /etc/fstab file. Obviously, if it can't mount something it's going to produce an error similar to that. In order to remove the message, edit your /etc/fstab file (as root) and remove the line that contains /media/3936-3939 as it no longer exists due to being removed (it maybe be a flash drive, those 8-character UUID's are usually FAT32 disks), deleting the partition, reformatting the partition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That seems there is something wrong with your laptop battery. Just follow up the troubleshooting steps as below to see the real issue:
1）To buy a [new battery](http://www.chargerbuy.com/laptop-battery.html) put into the notebook computer.

2）Disconnect the notebook adapter, use your laptop until it automatically shut down. This is a deep discharge process.

3）To connect adapter, the battery began to charge.

4）A charge until the battery is full.

5）The charge-discharge cycle repeated several times, your battery will reach the highest performance.

Refer to: http://www.lovebattery.net/batterytips.asp